# WiFi lag spikes after quiet period

Tags: sockets, networking, network-programming, udp

I have a simple client<>server setup where the client sends UDP packets to the server on say port 2000 many times per second. The server has a thread with an open BSD socket listening on  port 2000 and reads data using a blocking `recvfrom` call. That's it. I've set up a simple tic toc timer around the `recvfrom` call in the server and plotted the results when running this over Wifi.

[image: benchmark graph]

When the server is connected to the access point via  Wifi, it's similar in that usually the recvfrom call also take 0.015 seconds. However, after a short period of radio silence where no packets are sent (about half a second) the next packet that comes in on the server will cause the recvfrom call to take an extremely long time (between 0.6 and 3 seconds), followed by a succession of very quick calls (about 0.000005 seconds) and then back to normal (around 0.015 seconds). Here's some sample data:

```
0.017361 <--normal 
0.014914
0.015633
0.015867
0.015621
...      <-- radio silence
1.168011 <-- spike after period of radio silence
0.000010 <-- bunch of really fast recvfrom calls
0.000005
0.000006
0.000005
0.000006
0.000006
0.000005
0.015950 <-- back to normal
0.015968
0.015915
0.015646
```

If you look closely you can notice this on the graph.

When I connect the server to the access point over a LAN (i.e. with a cable), everything works perfectly fine and the recvfrom call always takes around 0.015 seconds. But over Wifi I get these crazy spikes.

What on earth could be going on here?

P.S. The server is running Mac OS X, the client is an iPhone which was connected to the access point via Wifi in both cases. I've tried running the client on an iPad and get the same results. The access point is a Apple Airport Extreme base station with a network that is extended using an Apple Airport Express. I've also tried with a Thompson router and a simple (non WDS network) and still get the same issue.

---

**UPDATE**

I rewrote the server part on Windows .NET in C# and tested it over the Wifi keeping everything else the same and the issue disappeared. So it suggests that it's a OS/network stack/socket issue on Mac OS X.

Comment: how busy is the wifi channel? this looks like bursted traffic caused by the MAC layer

Comment: Can you take a look using [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/download.html)?

Comment: @KillianDS There's about 5 Wifi devices on the network but they're all quiet.

Comment: @CodeCaster I could, what am I looking for?

Comment: First of all where the lag you experience occurs. If the packets flow over the air in realtime but lag in your application, there might be something OS- or network stack related. And what is the size of those packets you send?

Comment: @CodeCaster I wrote the networking part of the server in C# in .NET and tested it on a different computer running windows. Everything else is the same (same network, same router, same client, the new computer is also connected via Wifi). It works perfectly fine with no lag spikes. Suggesting the problem is with the OS/network stack on the OS X machine. What could it be? I thought it might be a problem with the BSD socket (maybe an option I didn't set) but it works fine over cable so it can't really be that can it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do anything about it. Several things can happen:

1. The WiFi MAC layer must allocate bandwidth slots to multiple users, it will usually try to give a user long enough time to send as much traffic as possible. But while other users are busy, this client can't send traffic. You even see this with only one user (consequence of the 802.11 protocol), but you'll notice this most with multiple active users of course.
2. IOS itself may have some kind of power saving and buffers packets for some time to send bursts, so it can keep some subsystems idle for a period of time.
3. You have some other radio signal that interferes.

This is not an exhaustive list, just what I could think of on short-notice with only the given input.

One thing: 0.6 to 3 seconds is not an extremely long time in the wireless domain, it might be 'long', but latency is with reason one of the biggest issues in all wireless communications. Don't forget that most wifi AP's are based on quite old specs, so I wouldn't say these numbers are extreme (I wouldn't expect 3s gaps however).